# Should we burninate the [security-by-obscurity] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, burninate-request

I came across the [security-by-obscurity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/security-by-obscurity) tag and wondered why we need it. If there is a reason for keeping the tag please enlighten me.

It contains 33 questions at the time of writing this. Only 9 of those are also have the [security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/security) tag.

**1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

Yes.

**2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

I guess so, but I would not recommend using security-by-obscurity to any developer. But maybe there are reasonable uses for it that I don't know of.

**3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

Yes.

**4.Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

Yes.

I would suggest deleting [security-by-obscurity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/security-by-obscurity) and retagging all of the questions with [security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/security) because people with low experiance in security might think it is a valid option if there is a tag for it. Furthermore I don't see why anyone would need that tag but that might be my ignorance.

Comment: Three times yes and one maybe? Sounds like a perfectly valid tag. I wouldn't recommend anyone to use Java either, but burninating the tag just because I don't like it is a bit of a stretch.

Comment: I do not think this tag causes any harm. The excerpt makes it clear that it is a security anti-pattern.

Comment: Wait, you answer "yes" to 3 of the 4 criteria to see if a tag is any good and you still insist on buninating it? What was the point of answering those criteria questions then?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, because as you concluded your self:

**1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

Yes.

**3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

Yes.

**4.Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

Yes.

and per the [guidance](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324071/578411), a tag must fail these criteria to even be considered for removal of the tag.